# ¿Cómo ordenar y reordenar numeros con una lista dado un número máximo?

Tags: python

Dado un número máximo (pongo 4 para el ejemplo, pero lo que busco es que se pueda introducir cualquier numero entero) quiero transferir a código este comportamiento

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
1
```

Es muy sencillo ver lo que sucede. De izquierda a derecha los numeros se van ordenando de menor (1) a mayor (4). Como le hemos dicho que el número máximo es 4, el primer grupo solo esta formado por 1 2 3 4.

A continuación se muestran los numeros reordenados en grupos de 3. Pero el máximo es 4, entonces cuando se llega a 1 2 3 la siguiente secuencia lógica es 1 2 4, porque hay que ordenarlos de menor a mayor. Y la siguiente secuencia lógica es 1 3 4.

A continuación se muestran los números reordenados en grupos de 2 (porque el grupo de tres ya no da más para reordenar).

Y al final se llega al grupo de 1 (que como es obvio si los numeros están ordenados de menor a mayor, aquí en este grupo solo puede existir el número 1).

Lo que yo he hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

```
numero_maximo=int(input("Introduce el numero maximo: "))
lista=[]
for i in range(1,numero_maximo+1):
    lista.append(i)
    print(lista)
```

Pero eso no es lo que yo busco, porque saca esto por pantalla:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Intenté de todo, bucles, condicionales,etcetera, pero no hay manera.

Comment: ¿Y en el grupo de 3 no sería válido el resultado: "2 3 4"? ¿Y en el grupo de 2? ¿No serían válidos los resultados: "2 3", "3 4" y "2 4"? ¿O siempre tiene que empezar la secuencia por 1? Respecto a tu código, lo único que haces en él es crear un array ordenado del 1 al número máximo y luego imprimirlo. No estás gestionando ninguna otra permutación.

Comment: Sí, la secuencia siempre tiene que empezar por 1, asi que no valdría que en el grupo de 3 empezara por "2 3 4", ni tampoco valdría que en el grupo de 2 empiece por "2 3". En mi codigo solo puse la aproximacion a la que llegué, lo sé, no quería extender más la pregunta con todos los intentos que hice con bucles y condicionales.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes ayudarte de las funciones que python te da en la biblioteca `itertools`. En concreto, tienes la función `combinations` que te da todas las combinaciones de N elementos tomados de M en M, ordenados. En tu caso N sería 4 y M iría variando desde 4 hasta 1. Así:

```
from itertools import combinations

N = 4
cifras = [str(i) for i in range(1, N+1)]
for M in range(N+1,0,-1):
  for c in combinations(cifras, M):
    print(" ".join(c))
```

Esto produce la salida:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
1
2
3
4
```

No obstante, mirando el ejemplo que has dado, aparentemente estás interesado tan sólo en las combinaciones que comienzan por 1 (no entiendo muy bien por qué). Es sencillo modificar el bucle anterior para que se salte las que no comienzan por 1:

```
from itertools import combinations

N = 4
cifras = [str(i) for i in range(1, N+1)]
for M in range(N,0,-1):
  for c in combinations(cifras, M):
    if c[0] != "1":
      continue      # Saltarsela
    print(" ".join(c))
```

Ahora la salida es:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
1
```

**Actualización**

La implementación anterior de "saltarse las que no empiezan por 1" es un tanto ineficiente, pues está computando muchas combinaciones que al final no serán mostradas. Esto puede mejorarse de una forma muy simple. Ya que el "1" es un elemento fijo al principio de todas las secuencias buscadas y no forma parte de las "combinaciones", ¿por qué no sacarle de nuestra lista de números? Haría mos las combinaciones de los números entre 2 y N, y a cada una de esas combinaciones le concatenaríamos después el "1" por delante. Hay que hacer un poco de trampa imprimiendo al final el caso "1" solo.

```
from itertools import combinations

N = 4
cifras = [str(i) for i in range(2, N+1)]
for M in range(N+1,0,-1):
  for c in combinations(cifras, M):
    print("1", " ".join(c))
print("1")
```

Resultado:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2
1 3
1 4
1
```

**Segunda actualización**

En lugar de imprimirlas, cada combinación (que es una tupla) se puede ir almacenando en una lista. Después esa lista se puede procesar como se quiera, o también obtener cuántos elementos tiene con `len(lista)`.

Así:

```
from itertools import combinations

N = 12

resultado = []
for M in range(N,0,-1):
  for c in combinations(range(2,N+1), M):
    resultado.append((1, *c))
resultado.append((1,))
```

La expresión `(1, *c)` crea una tupla con 1 como primer elemento y el resto de elementos de la tupla `c` "desempaquetados". La expresión `(1,)` es una tupla con un solo elemento (la coma es imprescindible para que python la reconozca como tupla).

En este caso he hecho `N=12`. La lista resultante tiene 2048 elementos, algunos de ellos son:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12),
 ...
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
 ...
 (1, 11),
 (1, 12),
 (1,)]
```

Comment: Eres un fenómeno! Muchas gracias. No entiendo por qué es necesario pasarlo como str(i) y no dejarlo como lista. ¿Cómo contaria los grupos que devuelve? Lo de las combinaciones que empiezan por 1 es porque este algoritmo sirve para deducir todas las escalas musicales de un sistema temperado, 1 equivale a la tónica (por ejemplo a DO). Si a tu algoritmo le pones N=12, te va a devolver todas las escalas musicales del sistema musical que se utiliza hoy en dia (si no recuerdo mal eran unas 24576). Solo tendrías que sustituir el 1 por DO, el 2 por DO#/REb, el 3 por RE, etc. Lo dicho, muchas gracias!

Comment: Lo pasé como `str` para hacer más fácil imprimirlas después, con el `" ".join(c)`. Si son números para imprimirlos habría que, o bien hacer un bucle interno, o bien `" ".join(map(str, c))` o `" ".join(str(i) for i in c)`

Comment: @ProfaneProgrammer He actualizado la respuesta con otra versión en la que en vez de imprimirlas, las combinaciones se guardan en una lista. Así puedes contarlas o procesarlas como prefieras.

Comment: Genio! Gracias, funciona perfecto. La convertí a lista la salida porque la tupla petaba o tardaba mucho. En la segunda actualizacion si que está bien 2048 (porque 2048*12= 24576). Sorry fue un lapsus mio, 2048 serian las escalas solamente en una tonica (que es lo que averigua el algoritmo que has escrito) y como hay 12 notas pues darian 24576 escalas totales en las doce tonalidades. Gracias crack.

Comment: De nada, no necesitas darme las gracias. Stackoverflow no es un foro, sino un lugar de preguntas y respuestas basado en reputación, como se explica [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). La forma de agradecer es puntuar.